# Want css based ul list menu to flow over page contents

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have
 1. an basically html page using css to create classic three column page and I have an
 2. `<ul>` file which generates a menu with CSS

and each works fine separately.

I'm trying to place the menu into the upper area of the main page but when I do so the menu will not expand fully below. It tries but bumps into the main page content < div>'s. So it truncates at the start of the three main columns.

If dropped into the page at the very bottom it works fine but that's no place for a menu... Ideally I would like the menu to be placed just above the main content.

---

ANSWER :
I INCREASED THE Z-INDEX SO THE DIV FLOATS ABOVE THE OTHER PAGE CONTENT. THAT FIXED RUNNING INTO (OR BELOW AS IT WERE) OTHER DIV'S Per code below.

---

See results http://cnew.org/index.php

```
<div id="dropmenu" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; 
height: 0px; 
z-index: 100;    <!---THIS LINE FIXED PROBLEM-->
top: 87px; left: 10px; visibility: visible;">   
<?php include('main-drop-down-menu.html'); ?>        
</div>    

 <div class="colmask threecol">    
        <div class="colmid">    
            <div class="colleft">    
                <div class="col1">    
                        <!-- Column 1 start --> 

The rest of the code here...
```

Comment: weird. I've been staring at this for a while trying to figure out what you're trying to do. So, with `<?php include( 'cnew-menu.php'); ?>` you're including the contents of your 2nd jsfiddle? Which Is a full html document with `<html>{and everythign in between}</html>`? There is quite a bit going on in all your example code. Would be much easier if you could create a minimal test case with just the problem you want to solve...

Comment: I had the include file inside the main page but it;s too big to leave there. (I think). However I will now create a test case as you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: This jsfiddle is all messed up http://jsfiddle.net/eaton9999/tbE3G/ you are trying to link to "external resources", but they're just local links to your own harddrive. You have to put those on the internet first. I'd like to help, and I imagine that there is a relatively simple fix, but as it stands, this question feels unanswereable, confusing, and a time suck. Please take the time to really clean it (and your example code) up and I will remove my `-1`.

Comment: Understood - will try my best at simplifying the question and providing files. Do not wish to waste your or anyone's goodwill and efforts!

Comment: @eaton9999 - Now that you figured out the solution (good job btw), could you update your question with a brief snippet that demonstrates the issue? ie So it sounds more like a "question". That will help others having the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by increasing the z-index of the drop down menu so that it is "on top" of all other elements. Apparently it was in fact populating correctly but was hidden behind the main < div >.
Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct then the problem is that your menu is not pushing the content down, correct?

This is happening becauase you have a fixed height on your `#menu` div. There's a very easy solution for this, see here:

```
#menu
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px; /* remove this line */
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    position:relative;
    float:left
}
```

Comment: Did try that - no luck in getting the bottom to expand below main body div's

Comment: Could you elaborate, not sure what you want.